# How to list out check constraints in a SQLite table

Tags: sqlite

for example I defined a table

```
create table demo_tab (
    name text not null unique,
    phone_number text not null check(phone_number like '9%')
);
```

is there any query to retrieve check and unique constraints of a table in SQLite

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the SQL that was used to create the table from `sqlite_master`:

```
sqlite> create table demo_tab (
   ...>     name text not null unique,
   ...>     phone_number text not null check(phone_number like '9%')
   ...> );
sqlite> select sql from sqlite_master where type='table' and name='demo_tab';
CREATE TABLE demo_tab (
    name text not null unique,
    phone_number text not null check(phone_number like '9%')
)
```

Comment: @DeveloperSuRu There is no better way.